# Upgraded to Mongoose 5.0.13 - getting a 500 in angular-fullstack generated app from a bluebird error: Error: expecting an array, a promise

Tags: angular, mongodb, mongoose, promise, bluebird

I have an app that I created using the angular-fullstack generator a *while* ago. All was well until we needed to upgrade our mongoose to get bulkwrite. Well then our socket.io broke when we got to mongoose 4.11.13 (or 4.>8. I don't recall the specific version but it was greater than 4.8 and < 5). Upgrading to Mongoose 5.0.13 solved the socket issue and has the bulkwrite however now most of the updates while they save to mongo they are throwing a 500 error with this:

> TypeError: expecting an array, a promise or a thenable
>
> See https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Error:-expecting-an->array,-a-promise-or-a-thenable
>
> PUT /api/accounts/57488f5ac260210300c10d80 500 77.719 ms - 2

Here is the method that's causing the error:

```
// Updates an existing Account in the DB
export function update(req, res) {
  if (req.body._id) {
    delete req.body._id;
  }
  Account.findByIdAsync(req.params.id)
   .then(handleEntityNotFound(res))
    .then(saveUpdates(req.body))
    .then(responseWithResult(res))
    .catch(handleError(res));
}
```

Which was from the boilerplate generator

I've narrowed it down to the saveUpdates(req.body) by removing the others. The update to the database happens and persists but them an error is caught.

This is the saveUpdates method - again from the generator.

```
function saveUpdates(updates) {
  return function(entity) {
    var updated = _.merge(entity, updates);
    return updated.saveAsync()
      .spread(updated => {
        return updated;
      });
  };
}
```

I think i've come close to finding other close resolutions and I've tried them but its not helping resolve the error.

Anyone hit this before or have an idea on how to refactor this to be able to use the latest mongoose?

Comment: What does `updated.saveAsync()` deliver and why does it need to be spread?

Comment: It is returning the updated record information. I'm not sure why it needs to be spread. It was part of the boiler plate code generated. Do you have a suggestion on a different method to do the save back through mongoose.

Comment: `.spread()` turns an array into a parameter list so `.spread(updated => {
        return updated;
      })` is a rather convoluted way to deliver the first element of the array delivered by `.saveAsync()`. That may not be wrong but it a rather odd way to go about things.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 Would you know if there is a better way that returns a promise instead? I'm assuming that this is the issue then? Or at least something I can put in there to return a promise as a test see if the error goes away?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Roamer-1888  I fixed the issue. From the angular-fullstack-generator the original boilerplate code doesn't work in mongoose 5.

The original boilerplate saveUpdates() was this:

```
function saveUpdates(updates) {
  return function(entity) {
    var updated = _.merge(entity, updates);
    return updated.saveAsync()
      .spread(updated => {
        return updated;
      });
  };
}
```

And based pm @Roamer-1888's note I made the following change and the 500 error went away:

```
function saveUpdates(updates) {
  return function(entity) {
    return _.merge(entity, updates).saveAsync()
      .then(updated => updated);
  };
}
```

Problem solved! Thank you @Roamer-1888

Comment: It's rather odd that the boilerplate version didn't work but this fixes it. The only thing I can think it that the dlivered member `updated` is Array-like (it has a 0th element). If it were a genuine Array, then I think the boilerplate would have worked.

BTW, the working code will simplify to `function saveUpdates(updates) {
 return function(entity) {
  return _.merge(entity, updates).saveAsync().then(updated => updated[0]);
 };
}`.

Comment: It definitely made a difference. I took your update thanks for the sleeker code.

Comment: Well in further testing i found that the [0] was actually causing any .then() on the call to the api to not work http.put(/url).then( console.log('this didn't work')); Removed the [0] and everything worked out. Also learned that the validator needed to change from return respond(true) to just return true - these were the other small mongoose 4->5 updates to the old boiler plate code.

Comment: In that case, it looks like you can remove `.then()` completely leaving `return _.merge(entity, updates).saveAsync()`.